# How to validate groups of multiple checkboxes with conditions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a large form which has multiple groups of checkboxes in it, I want to validate them when button is clicked and before fire up form action.
`<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" id="myform" method="POST">`

What I want to do is:

Example : if both `view[]`and `notselectedview` are not selected then it should alert (Please select at least one).

if one of them `view[]` or `notselectedview` is selected then fire up form action.

```html
Group One :
<div class="row g-2">
   <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="view[]" id="wA" value="A">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="wA">A</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="view[]" id="wB" value="B">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="wB">B</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-2">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="notselectedview" id="notselectedview" value="View not selected">
     <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="notselectedview">I dont wanna choose</label>
   </div>
</div>

Gorup Two :

<div class="row g-2">
   <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="ta" value="A">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="ta">A</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="tb" value="B">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="tb">B</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-2">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="notselectedtype" id="notselectedtype" value="Type not selected">
     <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="notselectedtype">I dont wanna choose</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

My tries: it alerts on page load instead of clicking on button.

```
$('.form-check-input').each(function() { 
  if($('.form-check-input input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {       
    alert('Please select atleast one!');  
  }
});
```

Then I changed to this `$("#mbtn").click(function(){` . [seen in action here please](http://jsfiddle.net/Netmaster/14ab3yst/1/)

Comment: So you want the user to select at least one checkbox from each group? Have you attempted a solution at all, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DavidThomas exactly that is what I want. I tried this `$('.form-check-input').each(function() {
  if($('.form-check-input input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
      alert('Please select atleast one!');
  }
});` but it alerts on page load instead of button click.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem where there's no obvious benefit in using jQuery, so I'm offering a plain JavaScript approach along with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// here we define the function to handle the validation, using Arrow syntax and passing
// in the Event Object from EventTarget.addEventListener():
const validate = (evt) => {
  // evt.currentTarget gets a reference to the element to which the event-listener was
  // bound:
  let clicked = evt.currentTarget,
    // here we retrieve the ancestor <form> element:
    form = clicked.form,
    // from the <form> we find all the <fieldset> elements with the the 'toValidate' class-name:
    groups = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset.toValidate');
    // we use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the returned NodeList:
    groups.forEach(
      // we pass in a reference to the current 'group' (the <fieldset> element),
      // and we toggle the 'invalid' class-name on that <fieldset>, according to the result
      // from the following assessment; if there are exactly zero <input> elements checked
      // the assessment returns Boolean true, and the class-name is added (if not already
      // present), otherwise if there is at least one checked <input> (as a negative length
      // is impossible so far as I'm aware), the assessment returns Boolean false and the
      // the specied class-name is removed (if alreay present) or simply not added:
        (group) => group.classList.toggle('invalid', group.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length === 0)
    );
}

// here we get a reference to all <button> elements with the class-name of 'checkValidity', and
// iterate over that NodeList using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
let check = document.querySelectorAll('button.checkValidity').forEach(
  // we use an anonymous Arrow function to pass in a reference to the current
  // <button> ('el') of the NodeList to the function body, in which we use
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the validate() function (note the
  // deliberately omitted parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'click'
  // event on that element:
  (el) => el.addEventListener('click', validate)
);
```

```css
:root {
  --contentWidth: clamp(30em, 50vw, 600px);
}

/* a very simple reset to ensure that all elements are sized
   according to the same layout, and share the same default
   margins, padding and font: */
*, ::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  /* using CSS logical properties to set the margin
     on the block axis of the content (perpendicular
     to the text-flow direction): */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* setting a margin of auto, to center the content,
     on the text-flow, the 'inline', axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* using a CSS custom property to set the width of
     the content: */
  width: var(--contentWidth);
}

fieldset {
  /* again using logical properties to set a 1em margin
     on the block axis: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* not using logical properties, because all padding
     is being set to the same size regardless of its
     axis, whether block or inline: */
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.controls {
  /* using display: flex to lay out the <button>
     elements: */
  display: flex;
  /* setting a 1em gap between adjacent elements: */
  gap: 1em;
  /* justifying the content so that the first, and last,
     elements will be against the inline borders (left
     and right, for English left-to-right language) and
     any remaining space will be spread between any
     adjacent elements: */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row > div {
  /* using flex layout again: */
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  /* justifying the content to the start of the inline
     content axis, or rather to the start of the flex
     axis; the default for 'display flex' is to lay the
     content out on the text-flow axis, so in English and
     left-to-right languages, this will position the elements
     to the left of the available space: */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

label,
button {
  /* here we specify that the <label> and <button> elements  that
     are positioned in a flex layout can grow to occupy available
     space: */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* and that those elements indicate interactivity with a pointer: */
  cursor: pointer;
}

legend {
  /* using logical properties again, here we're setting the borders
     of the element on the inline axis (the left and right borders
     in left-to-right languages): */
  border-inline-start: 1px solid #000;
  border-inline-end: 1px solid #000;
  /* and again for adding margin and padding: */
  margin-inline: 2em;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}

/* styling the <fieldset> element if it should have, or acquire, the
   invalid class-name: */
fieldset.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

/* styling the <p class="guidance"> element(s) to be effectively hidden
   by default, but retaining its space in the document layout in order
   to minimise content shifting when it appears: */
p.guidance {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* transitioning the opacity so that it fades in: */
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

/* when an ancestor element - in this demo the <fieldset>, but that's not
   specified in the CSS as it's written - acquires the 'invalid' class-name
   the opacity of the p.guidance element is changed from its default of 0 to
   1: */
.invalid p.guidance {
  color: #000f;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- I wrapped the posted elements in a <form> element: -->
<form action="#" method="post">
  <!-- I then wrapped the groups in <fieldset> elements, with the class of
       "toValidate" to provide an obvious hook for finding them later with
       JavaSCript: -->
  <fieldset class="toValidate">
    <!-- The group 'label' was wrapped in a <legend> element to effectively
         display it, and to allow for styling: -->
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <!-- while I dislike the cruft that Bootstrap, or possibly Material Design?,
         uses I left the original HTML alone (apart from wrapping it where
         appropriate) -->
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="view[]" id="wA" value="A">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="wA">A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="view[]" id="wB" value="B">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="wB">B</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="notselectedview" id="notselectedview" value="View not selected">
        <!-- here I corrected the spelling of "dont" to "don't," using an HTML entity for the apostrophe character: -->
        <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="notselectedview">I don&apos;t wanna choose</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- I added this '.guidance' paragraph, which is hidden by default, and shown when the <fieldset> is
         given the 'invalid' class-name; in order to avoid alerts() (which are an obnoxious UI, and transitory: -->
    <p class="guidance">Please select at least one option before submitting the form</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="toValidate">
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="ta" value="A">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="ta">A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="tb" value="B">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="tb">B</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="notselectedtype" id="notselectedtype" value="Type not selected">
        <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="notselectedtype">I don&apos;t wanna choose</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="guidance">Please select at least one option before submitting the form</p>
  </fieldset>
  <!-- I also added another <fieldset> to group relevant buttons together; in production I expect
       you'll check validity on hitting the submit button, but here I just used a generic <button>
       element with a class-name for JavaScript to use to identify the <button> to launch the checks: -->
  <fieldset class="controls">
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button class="checkValidity" type="button">Check</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xrnfjqew/).

With regards to the comment, below:

> when I click on button with `type="submit"` it fires up the form action and refreshing page even if form has errors[, I need] to disable submiting (*sic*) form if it has errors. [Is] it possible to change button or button type after all done?

Certainly, but first I'll offer an alternative which checks the form validity on page-load, and disables the submit button while any `<fieldset>` element is considered – by the function – to be invalid:

```js
const validate = (evt) => {
    let clicked = evt.currentTarget,
      form = clicked.form,
      groups = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset.toValidate'),
      // here we retrieve all the <button> elements in the <form> which either have no
      // 'type' attribute (and therefore have default form-submission functionality)
      // or whose 'type' attribute is equal to the 'submit':
      submitButtons = form.querySelectorAll('button:not([type]), button[type=submit]');

    // as before, we iterate over the <fieldset> elements using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
    groups.forEach(
      (group) => {
        // because we now add two classes dependent on the same condition, we cache the
        // number of <input> elements within the group which are checked, and whether
        // that count is equal to zero, in order to retrieve a Boolean true/false value:
        let check = group.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length === 0;
        // in the first instance we toggle the 'invalid' class-name based on the result
        // of the check variable:
        group.classList.toggle(
          'invalid',
          check
        );
        // in the second instance we toggle a new class-name 'showErrors' (since, on page-load,
        // I assume you didn't want to show errors to the client):
        group.classList.toggle(
          'showErrors',
          // if we have a trusted event (checking the 'isTrusted' property of the Event
          // Object), meaning the event was initiated by the user, *and* the check value
          // are both equal to true/truthy values we add the 'showErrors' class-name:
          evt.isTrusted && check
        );
      });

    // here we get a count of all <fieldset> elements which have an 'invalid' class-name:
    let invalidCount = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset.invalid').length;
    // we iterate over all submit <button> elements (as a <form> can have multiple submit
    // buttons:
    submitButtons.forEach(
      // and we update the disabled property of the <button> to reflect the assessment;
      // if the invalidCount is greater than zero (so we consider the form as a whole
      // invalid) the disabled property is set to true, so the <button> cannot be
      // used to submit the <form>:
      (btn) => btn.disabled = invalidCount > 0
    );
  },
  // we create a click event:
  clickEvent = new Event('click');

// on page load (or when this script is run), we iterate over the NodeList of <button>
// elements with a class-name of 'checkValidity':
document.querySelectorAll('button.checkValidity').forEach(
  (el) => {
    // and we bind the validate() function as the event-handler:
    el.addEventListener('click', validate);
    // and also we trigger/fire the created click event to cause the
    // validation check to run:
    el.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --contentWidth: clamp(30em, 50vw, 600px);
}

*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: var(--contentWidth);
}

fieldset {
  margin-block: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row>div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

label,
button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* using the 'not-allowed' cursor type to indicate that the
   submit button will not work: */

button:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

legend {
  border-inline-start: 1px solid #000;
  border-inline-end: 1px solid #000;
  margin-inline: 2em;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}

fieldset.showErrors {
  border-color: red;
}

p.guidance {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.showErrors p.guidance {
  color: #000f;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset class="toValidate">
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="view[]" id="wA" value="A">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="wA">A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="view[]" id="wB" value="B">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="wB">B</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="notselectedview" id="notselectedview" value="View not selected">
        <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="notselectedview">I don&apos;t wanna choose</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="guidance">Please select at least one option before submitting the form</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="toValidate">
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="ta" value="A">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="ta">A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="tb" value="B">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="tb">B</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="notselectedtype" id="notselectedtype" value="Type not selected">
        <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="notselectedtype">I don&apos;t wanna choose</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="guidance">Please select at least one option before submitting the form</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="controls">
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" class="checkValidity">Check</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xrnfjqew/1/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLButtonElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement).
- [`HTMLFieldsetElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldsetElement).
- [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort, its nice, but still having problem with form submiting, when I click on button with `type="submit"` it fires up the form action and refreshing page even if form has errors just same as my example http://jsfiddle.net/Netmaster/14ab3yst/12/ **need to disable submiting form if it has errors**. is it possible to change button or button type after all done ?

Comment: I've added another demo which seems to meet your needs as I understand them.